# jquery validate domain custom method

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, validation

Hi I'm new to jQuery and would like to learn how to use the validate function combined with RegExp to check if an input is correct, although I am unsure if this is the best way to do it.

The correct input should have this format:

integer.string.domain (ex: 1.myFirstDomain.com or 22.mySecondDomain.someInfo.org)

I've started out by trying to use the validate function with only numbers in the code below, just to see if I could get a simple RegExp to work, however it doesn't work, and I'm unsure of the best way to validate inputs including both numbers and strings in this particular format.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#testform").click("submit").validate({
    rules: {
      input: {
        numberInput: true
      }
    },
    messages: {
      input: "Please enter a number"
    }

  });
});

$.validator.addMethod('numberInput', function(value) {
  return /^[0-9]+$/.test(value);
}, 'Please only enter numeric values (0-9)');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.11.1/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>

<form id="testform">
  <p>InputTest</p>
  <input id="input" placeholder="Input domain here.">
  <br>
  <button id="submit" type="submit">Submit</button>
  <br>
</form>
```

Comment: `$("#testform").validate({`

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 issues here.

1. There is no need to call `click('submit')`, that will cause an error like `jquery-1.11.3.js:4670 Uncaught TypeError: ((jQuery.event.special[handleObj.origType] || (intermediate value)).handle || handleObj.handler).apply is not a function` when the button is clicked
2. The validator framework uses the element name to apply the rules, so add a name to the input

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#testform").validate({
    rules: {
      input: {
        numberInput: true
      }
    },
    messages: {
      input: "Please enter a number"
    }

  });
});

$.validator.addMethod('numberInput', function(value) {
  return /^[0-9]+$/.test(value);
}, 'Please only enter numeric values (0-9)');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.11.1/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>

<form id="testform">
  <p>InputTest</p>
  <input id="input" name="input" placeholder="Input domain here.">
  <br>
  <button id="submit-btn" type="submit">Submit</button>
  <br>
</form>
```

Comment: Thank you! It works now. I haven't asked questions on stackoverflow before, so forgive my ignorance, would it be better to create a new question in regards to how to format the input using RegExp, as i've described in this question?